# Invert index and columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a single row:

```
         10  20  30  70
data1:  2.3   5   6   7
```

I want to reindex the frame so that the column values (10, 20, 30, 70) become index values and the data becomes the column:

```
    data1:
10     2.3
20     5.0
30     6.0
70     7.0
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're looking for the [transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) ([`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)) method:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
         10  20  30  70
data1:  2.3   5   6   7

In [12]: df.T
Out[12]:
    data1:
10     2.3
20     5.0
30     6.0
70     7.0
```